# Shell Script to Zip all files above 1GB in a directory

Tags: shell-script, rhel, logs, zip

I need to create a script that will zip all files above size 1GB in my `/var/logs/*.log` files to `/var/logs/*.zip` .
eg: `access_log.log` to `access_log.zip` if its size is above 1024 MB.

Comment: Do you specifically require `zip` files or would you be satisfied with suitably compressed files?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want to reinvent `logrotate` or would you be satisfied with that as a solution?

Comment: Zip file is required as the server crashes after rewrite log file reaches size above 2gb

Comment: that doesn't really answer the question I asked. Do you _specifically_ require `zip` files, or would any compression (particularly one more native to UNIX/Linux systems) be acceptable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work (run from `/var/log`):

`find *.log -type f -size +1G |xargs -L1 -I file zip file.zip file`

**Explanation**

- `find *.log -type f -size +1G` Find all files greater than 1GB
- `xargs -L1 -I file zip file.zip file` Zip each file file

If you're on a multicore system (you probably are), you can run (for example) 4 zip commands in parallel by giving `xargs` the argument `-P4`.

If you're interested in saving a bit more space you might try giving `zip` the `-9` option.

Also, it's worth noting that `gzip`, `bzip2`, and `xz`/`lzip` are more common than Zip in the Unix world.

Answer (score 0):

look at find -size option  for that 
example for 1M :

```
find . -size +1M --exec gzip {} \;
```

**but**  If it is in /var/log folder you may prefer to use logrotate method to manage files historisation & automatic compressions

Comment: `gzip` doesn't produce zip files so you might want to explain that your two suggestions are both alternatives. (`logrotate` is good.)